# How to prevent pulling in git from different than the current branch

Tags: git, fetch, pull

Currently if you are in branch V2 and you do "git pull origin V3" it merges V3 to V2 and doesn't even warn or prompt about it.
Can this option somehow be blocked?
I read all the similar questions here and people suggest I can use fetch or show a warning in this case. This is OK, I will start using fetch instead of pull but I want to block other pull users.
Also, I assume there are cases when you have to make pull instead of fetch.
Thanks

Comment: Can you use just a plain `git pull` instead?  If your branch is set to track V2, then you should be fine.

Comment: `git pull` does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. I'd try using `git fetch` instead of `git pull`, as you've already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you link the remote branch as the local branch *upstream* source, you won't need to manually write the remote and branch.

```
# set upstream
git push -u origin V2

# Then simply pull from default branch
git pull
```

This'll work. Though, you're mostly always better to `fetch` and `rebase` your local branch on top of the remote. This make a cleaner and more usable history.

To answer the question directly though, you could create a custom *before merge* hook which check the branches being merged and alert when you're merging a remote branch not matching the local branch name. But, this is overhead and might be annoying as it'll check on every merge (because `git pull` === `git fetch && get merge`)